# Go to previous page and activate toggle

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular 9 project and I should activate a toggle when going back to a specific page and only in that case.

So actually when I go back from page **localhost:4200/y** to page **localhost:4200/x**, I turn on the toggle, otherwise if I go through *router.navigate* to page **localhost:4200/x**, the toggle should stay turned off.

The go back button typescript is like this:

```
export class BackToPreviousComponent() {
  @Input() labelPrevious: string;

  back(): void {
    history.back();
  }
}
```

this is its HTML:

```
<a (click)="back()" class="btn btn-nav">
  <i class="icon-back pr-1"></i>
  {{ labelPrevious }}
</a>
```

and this is how is fitted in the application:

```
<div class="component">
  <app-back-to-previous [labelPrevious]="'random text'"></app-back-to-previous>
  ...
</div>
```

So how can I tell the application to turn on the toggle only in this case?

Comment: You can use the query parameters and check them

Comment: Could you be more specific?